# SQL to retrieve parent-child relationship in parent-child order, from a self referencing table

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I use the following query to retrieve the parent-child relationship data, from a table which is self referencing to the parent.

```
    -- go down the hierarchy and get the childs
    WITH ChildLocations(LocationId, FkParentLocationId, [Level]) 
        AS 
        (
            (
                -- Start CTE off by selecting the home location of the user
                SELECT l.LocationId, l.FkParentLocationId, 0 as [Level]
                FROM   Location l
                WHERE  l.LocationId = @locationId
            )
            UNION ALL 
            -- Recursively add locations that are children of records already found in previous iterations.
            SELECT l2.LocationId, l2.FkParentLocationId, [Level] + 1
            FROM   ChildLocations tmp
                   INNER JOIN Location l2
                        ON  l2.FkParentLocationId = tmp.LocationId
        )
    INSERT INTO @tmp
    SELECT * from ChildLocations;
```

The table has the following fields:
LocationId, FkParentLocationId, FkLocationTypeId, etc...

This works fine, but how I want to retrieve it is as follows:

```html
Parent 1
    Child 1
    Child 2
      Child 21
    Child 3
      Child 31
Parent 2
    Child 4
    Child 5
    Child 6
```

What is currently gives is like:

```html
Parent 1
Parent 2
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
    Child 4
 etc....
```

How can I modify the above to get it in the order I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to append an 'order' field? This may be an approach:

```
WITH ChildLocations(LocationId, FkParentLocationId, [Level]) 
    AS 
    (
        (
            -- Start CTE off by selecting the home location of the user
            SELECT l.LocationId, l.FkParentLocationId, 0 as [Level],
                   cast( str( l.locationId ) as varchar(max) ) as orderField
            FROM   Location l
            WHERE  l.LocationId = @locationId
        )
        UNION ALL 
        -- Recursively add locations that are children ...
        SELECT l2.LocationId, l2.FkParentLocationId, [Level] + 1,
               tmp.orderField + '-' + 
               str(tmp.locationId) as orderField
        FROM   ChildLocations tmp
               INNER JOIN Location l2
                    ON  l2.FkParentLocationId = tmp.LocationId
    )
SELECT * from ChildLocations order by orderField;
```

Remember than `Order by` in an `Insert` is not allowed.

[Take a look a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9edef/8/0)

Comment: I'm getting error Invalid column name orderfield in 'l2.orderField'

Comment: Fixed but not tested with your schema. See this simple sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9edef/8/0

Comment: It works up to one level, but not further than that. I mean I have multiple levels. Modified the question.

Comment: It works for all levels, see sqlfiddle sample with 3 levels, look the last field, `o` field.